# trying to execute a particular python script but another script is executed

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I'm trying to execute the below script(its incomplete) in cmd 'python whatsapp.py'

```
import time
import pyautogui
import subprocess
from tkinter import * 
# gui begins
class App:
    def main():
        win = Tk()
        win.geometry("300x100")
        win.title("WhatsApp Texter")

        name = Label(win, text = "Name:")
        name.grid(row = 2, column = 2 )

        name_textb = Entry(win, bd = 5)
        name_textb.grid(row = 2, column = 4)

        msg = Label(win, text = "Message:")
        msg.grid(row = 4, column = 2 )

        msg_textb = Entry(win, bd = 5, width = "30")
        msg_textb.grid(row = 4, column = 4)

        # functions for buttons to perform
        def clear_func():
            name_textb.delete(0, 'end')
            msg_textb.delete(0, 'end')

        def send_func():
            receiver = name_textb.get()
            text = msg_textb.get()
            # print(receiver, text)
            subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Users\JasonPC\AppData\Local\WhatsApp\WhatsApp.exe")
            win.destroy()

        def exit_func():
            win.destroy()

        clear_btn = Button(win, text = "Clear", command = clear_func)
        clear_btn.grid(row = 10, column = 2)

        send_btn = Button(win, text = "Send", command = send_func)
        send_btn.grid(row = 10, column = 4)

        exit_btn = Button(win, text = "Exit", command = exit_func)
        exit_btn.grid(row = 10, column = 6)

        win.mainloop()
        # gui ends
class Texter(App): # Texter inherites App (Single Inheritance)
    def mousecontrol():
        time.sleep(10) # waits for WhatsApp to load
        pyautogui.moveTo(97, 134, duration = 0.25) # moves cursor to search bar
        pyautogui.click(97, 134) # clicks on search bar
        keyboardcontrol()
    def keyboardcontrol():
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App.main()
```

But when I run this script in cmd another cmd window pops out and runs a script called 'guiV2.py'

I dont know whats the issue.
[image]

These are two cmd windows which open up when I run the whatsapp.py script. I'm not sure if it's something to do with 'pyautogui package'.

need help, 
cheers

Comment: Didn't fix it! Still looking out for a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you see the trace, the first line, it's been called from module `pyautogui`

Comment: I honestly don't know what that means

Comment: So you need to check the pyautogui documentation. Reason - in your python script, second line `import pyautogui` tries to load pyautogui, which in turn loads couple of other modules. You need to read the error stacktrace in you cmd window when you run your python file. Looking at the documentation will help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. There is `cmd.py` in the same directory as my script, so `pyautogui` calls that `cmd.py` instead of its dependency modules which is also named `cmd.py`